# Catkin_make skips new package

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner with ROS, working through chapter 2 of the Learning ROS for Robotics Programming book (2nd ed).  When I use catkin_create_pkg it appears to execute normally (my terminal output matches the output shown in the book).  I then change directory to my workspace and execute catkin_make.  This completes without any errors, but it fails to acknowledge my new package.  Using rospack find also fails to find the package.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help in advance!

Edit: here's requested data to help diagnose my problem.

#Terminal input/output for catkin_make:

```
viki@c3po:~$ cd ~/dev/catkin_ws
viki@c3po:~/dev/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/viki/dev/catkin_ws
Source space:
/home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/src Build
space: /home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/build
Devel space:
/home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/devel Install
space:
/home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in
"/home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/viki/dev/catkin_ws/build"
#### viki@c3po:~/dev/catkin_ws$ rospack find chapter2_tutorials
[rospack] Error: stack/package
chapter2_tutorials not found
```

#CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(chapter2_tutorials)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES chapter2_tutorials
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(chapter2_tutorials
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/chapter2_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
# add_executable(chapter2_tutorials_node src/chapter2_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(chapter2_tutorials_node chapter2_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(chapter2_tutorials_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS chapter2_tutorials chapter2_tutorials_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_chapter2_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

#package.xml:

```
<package>
  <name>chapter2_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The chapter2_tutorials package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag --> 
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="viki@todo.todo">viki</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  <!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/chapter2_tutorials</url> -->


  <!-- Author tags are optional, mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Authors do not have to be maintianers, but could be -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> -->


  <!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->
  <!-- Examples: -->
  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> -->
  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
  <!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <!--   <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> -->
  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234449/catkin_make-skips-new-package/) by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-17**:
Is this new package in a catkin workspace? (i.e. did you call `catkin_init_workspace` in the `src` folder?)
In which directory are you calling `catkin_make`?

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-17**:
Yes, I can confirm that `catkin_init_workspace` was executed because when I tried it just now, it echoed: ~"/dev/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already exists.  I execute `catkin_make` in ~/dev/catkin_ws as instructed by the tutorial.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-18**:
did you then `source ~/dev/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`? If not, please edit your question with the output of `catkin_make` (copy-paste, please no screenshot),  as well as with the contents of `package.xml` and `CMakelists.txt`.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-18**:
Following my tutorial, I edited my ~/.bashrc file by `echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`.  So this step should be taken care of when I restart the terminal.  In case it is helpful for you, I added the data you requested.  Sorry about the formatting.  It was better when previewed.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-18**:
And thanks for your continued support!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-19**:
@adiadidas15 please reupload this and format it properly ;-) It is so hard to read like this.
I.e. just copy-paste directly from the file, mark it, and then hit the button with the 101010 on it. This is code formatting.

Also, we need the `CMakelists.txt` of your package, not the top-level one.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-19**:
You need to source your workspace, i.e. not only `source  /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` (and I would actually go to a more recent version like indigo or soon kinetic), but source `~/dev/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. Otherwise, it will not find anything because `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` needs to contain

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-19**:
the path to your workspace. Otherwise, it is clear why it does not find your package. It is just not on your path.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-19**:
mig, thanks so much for your help!  It turns out that sourcing ~/dev/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash fixed my problem.  The tutorial book I purchased gave the misleading statement "this step is only to reload the the `setup.bash` file.  You will obtain the same result if you close and open a new shell."

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-19**:
I am using Hydro so that I can follow along with the book I purchased.  I plan on using Indigo after working through the tutorials.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-19**:
Well, it seems I spoke too soon about resolving my problem.  `rospack find` is now able to find my new package.  However, `catkin_make` still does not build the package.  `rosrun` is not able to find the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should first run `source ~/dev/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and if you use `rosbuild`(which is not your case) from the terminal  `echo "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"~/dev/yourfoldername:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}" >> ~/.bashrc`
or manually add this `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"~/dev/yourfoldername:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}` at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file

You did forget to edit your `CMakelists.txt` as it is in the book in the paragraph **Building the node**

```
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a src/example1_a.cpp) 
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
```

And in the book there are using `Rosbuild` package, but if you want to use `catkin`, just edit your `CMakelists.txt` as follow

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(example1_a src/example1_a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example1_a ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(example1_a chapter2_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example1_b ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(example1_b chapter2_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
Thanks ROSkinect for your advice.  What I said above is based on pages 43 & 44 of the book, which indicate that the following commands will result in the built package:

```
cd ~/dev/catkin_ws/src
catkin_create_pkg chapter2_tutorials std_msgs roscpp
cd ~/dev/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
Do you agree, or am I misreading the book?  Thinking that the source devel/setup.bash was the reason for catkin_make failing to compile my project, I went forward in the chapter and added the code which you kindly provided from pages 56 through 60.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
Unfortunately, when I execute `catkin_make chapter2_tutorials` mentioned on page 60, the package still isn't built.  So I am still baffled about what I am getting wrong...

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
I also just noticed that you mentioned the book using `Rosbuild`, however, in my book (Second Edition) I cannot find `Rosbuild` being mentioned anywhere in chapter 2.  Where do you see this at?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-21**:
I edited my answer, check it out

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-22**:
ROSkinect, thanks for all your help.  As I explained to mig, I decided to start the tutorial over in a new workspace and was able to complete it successfully.  I still don't know why my original package wouldn't build, but that is okay...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosrun` does not find anything, because you do not build anything. I.e. there is no executable.

In the `CMakelists.txt`, you need to tell `CMake`, which is called by `catkin_make`, which source files you want to compile into which executable.
This is what the `add_executable` and `add_library` calls are for. Check the book, this should be explained therein and you probably just need to uncomment the respective lines, together with the `target_link_libraries` calls for the respective targets.
Or check [the wiki tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
Thanks for your continued help mig.  My book did not mention adding the `add_executable()`, `add_dependencies()` & `target_link_libraries()` until later in the chapter.  Unfortunately, adding this code (mentioned above by ROSkinect) still does not resolve my problem.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-20**:
The book does not mention adding `add_libraries()` as you mentioned.  Do you think this could be my problem?

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-21**:
I took a look at the wiki tutorial for this same node building exercise.  My `CMakeLists.txt` is consistent with what the wiki defined.  I also tried `catkin_make --force-cmake`, which didn't fix the problem.  And I tried `catkin_make -pkg chapter2_tutorials`, which replied with package not found.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-21**:
But `rospack find chapter2_tutorials` is successful in finding the package.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-21**:
I just edit my answer

Probably we don't have the same book or the same edition

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-21**:
Thanks for all your help mig.  After trying to figure out what was preventing my package from building for several nights, I decided to start over from scratch with a new workspace.  Knowing what I know now I was able to complete the tutorial.  I still am not sure what kept my package from building.

**Comment by [adiadidas15](https://answers.ros.org/users/26878/adiadidas15/) on 2016-05-22**:
Pointing out that I needed to source `devel/setup.bash` was one crucial element I was missing, so thanks for diagnosing this for me!

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2016-05-22**:
That was my last editing for ;)
everything is crucial and has a reason behind it.. Good luck